# How i can deploy a genexus c# in a shared hosting?

Tags: c#, genexus

I need to deploy a genexus C# in a shared hosting.

I only have access to the ftp, so my idea is put in **public_html** the files that i have in **C:/Models/Project/CSharpModel/web** but i don't know if this will work because i never put this archives in a shared hosting, only in a IIS.

Someone can explain me how the genexus will create the database/tables of my application?

There's some else that i have to do?

Comment: Regardless of how you pack the binaries you want to deploy (@sebagomez left really good tips on his answer), you need to make sure the share you have access with FTP (or some folder underneath), has a virtual dir configured in IIS. If IIS is only serving static content from there, the .Net application won't start.

Comment: @Fede i have access with FTP, there's a way to check via FTP if the IIS is serving one directory?

Comment: @Fede i put the archives in public_html and www, but both i can't find the rest apis, in this case, i have to enter in contact with my hoster?

Comment: sorry, there is no way to tell that from FTP. The provider should give you some kind of documentation instructing how to deploy a .Net application in that folder. Also note that there are some requirements for Rest services in order tu run properly, that aren't installed by default, such as UrlRewrite. Your provider should  confirm if that component is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take of the database reorganization yourself. Keep in mind thou, that GeneXus has a feature called [Export Reorganization](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34476,Export%20Reorganization) that will allow you to export a reorganization program, and the doc tells you how to execute that reorg program.

Also, I wouldn't copy the entire web directory in your shared folder. You should use the [Deploy Engine](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32092,Application%20Deployment%20tool) in order to get the only minimum required file for your app.

**Edit:** You need to copy the folder where all the files are placed... commonly there's a folder named after the Deployment Unit's name, and inside that folder, on folder for every deploy you've made. Those folder are named after a timestamp, so you'll easily find the latest deploy.

Comment: In my case, i have a shared hosting. i have to choose the "local" option?

Comment: after i generate the deploy, which folder i have to put the archives in my server? i put in public_html but i'm not finding my apis

Comment: You need to copy the folder where all the files are placed... commonly there's a folder named after the Deployment Unit's name, and inside that folder, on folder for every deploy you've made. Those folder are named after a timestamp, so you'll easily find the latest deploy. (This is going to the anwer)